# Data preparation for neural network in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to learn how to prepare data for training samples in python. I found a simple example of a neural network that predicts the stock price. At the moment I am not interested in the accuracy of training the network, but I am interested in how to take any data and prepare it for submission to the neural network.

As an example, I took these stocks over the past 5 years. As planned, the neural network accepts data for the last 50 days as input and predicts the course for the next 5 days. To do this, I read the .csv file, processed the data in such a way that after the transformation I got two dataframes, the first one is responsible for the input data, and the second for the output.

The problem is, no matter what I do, I keep getting errors and so I cannot complete the training. What am I  doing wrong? The code is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import torch
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import pandas_profiling as pprf
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Input, MaxPooling1D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling1D, Conv1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from IPython.display import display, Image

random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

data = pd.read_csv('F:\\YNDX_ME.csv')[::]

data = data.drop('Date',axis=1)
data = data.drop('Adj Close',axis=1)
data = data.drop(np.where(data['Volume'] == 0)[0])
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)

#profiler = pprf.ProfileReport(data)
#profiler.to_file(r'F:\profiling.html')

days_edu = 50
days_pred = 5
df_edu_list = []

for i in range(len(data.index)-days_edu-days_pred+1):  
    df_temp = []
    for j in range(days_edu):
        df_temp.extend(data.loc[i+j,:].tolist())
    df_edu_list.append(df_temp)


df_edu_out_list = []
for i in range(len(data.index)-days_edu-days_pred+1):  
    df_temp = []
    for j in range(5):
        df_temp.extend(data.loc[i+j+days_edu,:].tolist())
    df_edu_out_list.append(df_temp)
    
df_edu_train = pd.DataFrame(df_edu_list[:int(len(df_edu_list)*0.8)])
df_edu_val = pd.DataFrame(df_edu_list[int(len(df_edu_list)*0.8):])        
df_edu_train_out = pd.DataFrame(df_edu_out_list[:int(len(df_edu_out_list)*0.8)])
df_edu_val_out = pd.DataFrame(df_edu_out_list[int(len(df_edu_out_list)*0.8):])

df_edu_train = normalize(df_edu_train.values)
df_edu_val = normalize(df_edu_val.values)
df_edu_train_out = normalize(df_edu_train_out.values)
df_edu_val_out = normalize(df_edu_val_out.values)

df_edu_train = np.expand_dims(df_edu_train,axis=0)
df_edu_train_out = np.expand_dims(df_edu_train_out,axis=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding="same", strides=1, input_shape= (959,250),data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 5))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 5))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation=None))

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 1000

model.fit(df_edu_train, df_edu_train_out, epochs=EPOCHS)
```

```
Error:
InvalidArgumentError:  Conv2DCustomBackpropFilterOp only supports NHWC.
     [[node gradient_tape/sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/Conv2DBackpropFilter
 (defined at C:\Users\nick0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:464)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1046]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradient_tape/sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/Conv2DBackpropFilter:
In[0] sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/ExpandDims (defined at C:\Users\nick0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py:231) 
In[1] gradient_tape/sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/ShapeN:    
In[2] gradient_tape/sequential/conv1d/Conv1D/Reshape:
```

Update:
Changed `data_format = 'channels_first'` to `data_format = 'channels_last'`. The training began, but as I understood, the training took place on the entire training set, i.e. the neural network just thought that there was one example and it was trained on it specifically. How to make the neural network take each line in turn? is each line essentially a separate example?

Comment: a "Netural Network" is some kind of Natural Neural Network?

Comment: Changed data_format = 'channels_first' to data_format = 'channels_last'. The training began, but as I understood, the training took place on the entire training set, i.e. the neural network just thought that there was one example and it was trained on it specifically. How to make the neural network take each line in turn? is each line essentially a separate example?

Comment: Please do not add info or ask questions in the comments; edit & update your post accordingly instead